# Python. Заменить подстроку вначале текстовой строки в датафрейме на основании другого датафрейма

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Есть два датафрейма:

```
reference = [['поселок ', 'поселок'], ['посёлок ', 'поселок'], ['п ', 'поселок'], ['п. ', 'поселок']]
reference = pd.DataFrame(reference, columns = ['dirty', 'clean'])

data = [['посёлок Подгорный'], ['посeлок Глинка'], ['п. Новокамышенка']]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['setll'])
```

Хочу сделать проверку: если setll из data начинается на одно из значений dirty из reference, то из setll извлечь dirty.
Пробую так:

```
def extract_settl_type(df_column):
    for dirty, clean in reference.itertuples(index=False):
        if df_column.startswith(dirty):
            setll_norm = df_column.replace(dirty, '')
            setll_type_norm = clean
            return setll_norm, setll_type_norm
        else:
            return None
    
data['setll_norm'] = data['setll'].apply(extract_settl_type)
```

Но возвращается None:
| |setll    | setll_norm |
| --------- |--------- | -------------- |
|0  |посёлок Подгорный  |None|
|1  |посeлок Глинка |None|
|2  |п. Новокамышенка   |None|

Хотя если пробовать на отдельном значении:

```
strr = 'посёлок Подгорный'
for dirty, clean in reference.itertuples(index=False):
    if strr.startswith(dirty):
        print(dirty)
```

То возвращается "посёлок ", то есть не None.
Камрады, что я упускаю в функции extract_settl_type? :с

Answer (score 0):

Немного оптимизировал и поменял нейминги.
Если я правилно понял задачу, то вот мой вариант:

```
import pandas as pd

references = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['dirty', 'clean'],
    data=[['посёлок', 'поселок'],
          ['п', 'поселок'],
          ['п.', 'поселок']]
)
data = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['raw_locality'],
    data=[['посёлок Подгорный'],
          ['посeлок Глинка'],
          ['п. Новокамышенка']]
)


def locality_type_replacer(raw_str: str) -> str:
    """
    Replace locality type
    """
    split_string: list = raw_str.split(" ")
    raw_type = split_string[0] if len(split_string) > 1 else None

    # Check raw_type exist, raw_type in references, string starts of raw_type
    if not any((
            raw_type,
            raw_type in tuple(references['dirty']),
            raw_str.startswith(raw_type)
    )):
        return raw_str

    # Get index for mapping
    index = references.dirty[references.dirty == 'п'].index

    # Get value for rename
    mapped_value = references.clean[index].item()

    # Replace locality type
    split_string[0] = mapped_value

    return ' '.join(split_string)


data['locality'] = data['raw_locality'].apply(locality_type_replacer)
data
```

[image: result]